# difference between isgraph() and iscntrl() functions:

Tags: c

Regarding the functions `isgraph()` and `iscntrl()`:

What is the difference between these functions in C?

Can anybody explain what is the difference between them and in what situation they are used?

Comment: Handy chart here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isgraph

Comment: Have you looked at the man pages for those functions?

Comment: @RetiredNinja: That link does not answer the question because it does not make clear whether a space “has a graphical representation” or what is the difference between `isgraph` and `iscntrl`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, it's a comment, not an answer, and the chart is clear to me. I guess ymmv. *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

c 2018 7.4.1.6 2 says:

> The `isgraph` function tests for any printing character except space (`’ ’`).

C 2018 7.4.1.4 2 says:

> The `iscntrl` function tests for any control character.

C 2018 7.4 3 says:

> The term *printing character* refers to a member of a locale-specific set of characters, each of which occupies one printing position on a display device; the term *control character* refers to a member of a locale-specific set of characters that are not printing characters.

Therefore, the `isgraph` characters, space, and the `iscntrl` characters form a partition of the set of characters: Each character in the set is in exactly one of those three subsets. So `isgraph` and `iscntrl` are complements except for the space character, which is neither of them.

There may be `unsigned char` codes that do not correspond to any characters in the locale-specific set of characters. Since such codes are not in the set of characters, neither `isprint` nor `iscntrl` returns true (non-zero) for them, nor do they represent a space.

Comment: I am not sure about the partition: what about bytes beyond 127 in the C locale?

Comment: @chqrlie: Interesting. Updated. They do partition the set of characters but do not partition the `unsigned char` values.

Comment: You might also give the OP insight about `isgraph()` and `isprint()` domain definition: the values of type `unsigned char` plus the special unsigned int value `EOF`. Hence `char` values should be cast as `(unsigned char)` for defined behavior.

Comment: They partition single-byte characters which are defined in the current locale. If you use a locale which defines single-byte characters with codes greater than 127, then you'll probably find such characters in the sets recognised by `is*`. But UTF-8 locales do not define such characters.